# Microsoft.OData.Client with Microsoft.OData.Core 7.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, swagger

I would need to use Microsoft.OData.Client in my project, wich already reference Microsoft.OData.Core 7.0.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.OData 6.0.

Actually i don't find version of client that's compatible with Microsoft.OData.Core 7.0.0 and later.

Last version supported by client is 6.15.
Microsoft.OData.Client (6.15.0) requires Microsoft.OData.Core (= 6.15.0).

Do we have a new version of OData.Client in the horizon that will use Core>=7 and match the one used by the AspNet package?

Any other solutions in the meantime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i keep the client part based on 6.15 Odata version and Simple.OData.Client 4.20, 
Server part will be upgraded to odata 7.0 
It works well provided you use the timestamp type on client in remplacement of system.DateTime or Microsoft.OData.Edm.Library.Date Types